# Pass data to methods in Vue from template

Tags: methods, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue.JS in my build in visualforce page.

I have below piece of Vue template code where I am able to get **acc.name** print on page. But now I need to send this value to **addtoterriotry** method inside **methods** section of Vue app.

Please find below my Vue app component.

```
<v-dialog v-model="addToTerr" max-width="1000">\
                    <v-card>\
                        <v-card-title class="headline">Review Selected Accounts</v-card-title>\
                        <v-card-text>\
                            <div v-for="acc in this.items" v-if="acc.selected">{{acc.Name}}</div>\
                        </v-card-text>\
                        <v-card-actions>\
                            <v-btn color="secondary" v-on:click="addToTerriotry">Add</v-btn>\
                            <v-btn v-on:click="addToTerr = false">Close</v-btn>\
                        </v-card-actions>\
                    </v-card>\
                </v-dialog>\
```

**addtoterriotry method :**

```
   methods: {
                selectDeselectAccount: function (props) {
                    props.item.selected = props.item.selected ? false : true;
                    if (props.item.selected)
                        this.accountsSelected = this.accountsSelected + 1;
                    else
                        this.accountsSelected = this.accountsSelected - 1;
                },
                showaccount: function (props) {
                    this.selectedaccount = props.item;
                    this.accdetails = true;
                },
                addToTerriotry: function () {
                    alert('Invoke Controller Action');
                   // Fetch acc.name value here.
                     CallApexMethod();


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean that you are trying to access the `acc` with a `selected` value of `true`, just find that element from the `items` array at the beginning of your `addToTerriotry` method:

```
addToTerriotry: function () {
  alert('Invoke Controller Action');
  let acc = this.items.find(i => i.selected);
  console.log(acc.name);  
  CallApexMethod();
}
```